# Companion object in fragment vs shared preferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

Sometimes to use data from other fragment I use companion object as below

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment()  {
[...]

companion object {
   val myValueToShare = 20f
   }
}
```

in other fragment I use this variable as:

i.e.

```
ExampleFragment.myValueToShare = 10f
```

Is it alright? Is it better to i.e. use `shared preferences`.
Which methods from above are more light and why?

[https://blog.mindorks.com/companion-object-in-kotlin#:~:text=So%2C%20by%20declaring%20the%20companion,front%20of%20the%20object%20declaration](https://blog.mindorks.com/companion-object-in-kotlin#:%7E:text=So%2C%20by%20declaring%20the%20companion,front%20of%20the%20object%20declaration).

Comment: `Is it alright?` depends on your definition of `alright`. is this a code smell or a bad practice ? i would say most likely. saving it into shared preferences to achieve the same thing is probably also going to be a code smell or a bad practice, because why aren't you passing these values to where they need to be ? saving them to persistent storage just to have access to them isn't necessary, same with have a static reference to them

Comment: Alright then, what would be a solution for it?

Comment: If I dont want to instance the other class?

Comment: and navigation args doesn't work here :)

Comment: `and navigation args doesn't work here` well that's not true, but even if you don't want to use nav args, the typical approach is to use a shared base activity and save these values there, perhaps if you're using mvvm you can make use of a shared viewmodel

Comment: Base fragment, base activity sounds good..
Alright shared viewmodel sounds good if you make it between fragments.
My case is quite specific I have class TutorialWorkListView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
    : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { }
and here I use this companion object from base abstract fragment  here(TutorialView) I use:
ExampleFragment.myValueToShare = 10f

Comment: shared base activity means that you have a single activity which manages your fragments, then you can save common variables to that activity and have access to them when you need them, similar to how you would have a viewmodel attached to the the activity and not the fragments